# How to return multiple viewbag data to view from controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, openweathermap

I am using weather API in which user search weather for specific City or Country from view which is receive by controller as parameter,information about weather is completely working but I am just unable to return all that information back to view from controller.

view for search

```
<form action="searchbyname" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="weather" placeholder="Find your location...">
    <input type="submit" value="Find">               
</form>
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult searchbyname(string weather)
        {
            string appId = "f40a39abac667183c127adefffcf88ed";
            string url = string.Format("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={0}&units=metric&APPID={1}", weather, appId);
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                string json = client.DownloadString(url);
                if (json.IndexOf("Error") == -1)
                {

                    WeatherInfo weatherInfo = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<WeatherInfo>(json);
                    ViewBag.citycountry = weatherInfo.name + "," + weatherInfo.sys.country;
                    ViewBag.ImageUrl = string.Format("http://openweathermap.org/images/flags/{0}.png", weatherInfo.sys.country.ToLower());
                    ViewBag.des = weatherInfo.weather[0].description;
                    //weatherimage
                    ViewBag.ImageUrl = string.Format("http://openweathermap.org/img/w/{0}.png", weatherInfo.weather[0].icon);
                    ViewBag.temp = string.Format("{0}°С", Math.Round(weatherInfo.main.temp, 1));

                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

View in which data should be shown

```
<table id="tblWeather" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display:none">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">
        Weather Information
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3">
        <img id="imgWeatherIcon" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span id="citycountry">@ViewBag.citycountry</span>
        <img id="imageurl" src="@ViewBag.ImageUrl" />
        <span id="des">@ViewBag.des</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

> Model class

```
public class ClimateModel
    {
        public class WeatherInfo
        {
            public Coord coord { get; set; }
            public Sys sys { get; set; }
            public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
            public Main main { get; set; }
            public int dt { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
        }

        public class Coord
        {
            public double lon { get; set; }
            public double lat { get; set; }
        }

        public class Sys
        {
            public string country { get; set; }
        }

        public class Weather
        {
            public string main { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string icon { get; set; }
        }

        public class Main
        {
            public double temp { get; set; }
            public double temp_min { get; set; }
            public double temp_max { get; set; }
            public int humidity { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not create a *Model* as in [*Model-View-Controller*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2) instead of using the viewbag (which isn't technically a model).

Comment: @ErikPhilips actually I have model class and also want to use that but could not understand how to use inside controller because the  model class (weatherinfo) is already use to get data from API .You can see the weatherinfo object is used.Do tell me the way how can i use .I edited my question, added model class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing some concepts between `WebForms` and `MVC`. There is no `runat="server"`, `asp:Label` or `asp:Image` on `MVC`. You must use with pure HTML elements.

Your code should looke like:

```
<table id="tblWeather" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display:none">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
            Weather Information
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img id="imgWeatherIcon" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="citycountry">@ViewBag.citycountry</span>
            <img id="imageurl" src="@ViewBag.ImageUrl" />
            <span id="des">@ViewBag.des</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT 1:** As @erik-philips pointed out, you should really create a model class.

**EDIT 2:** Take a look at [HTML Helpers](https://dzone.com/articles/working-with-built-in-html-helper-classes-in-aspne). The can make your life easier when binding models to views.

Answer (score 0):

As Erik pointed out in his comment you could use a model to capture the api response, and then put it either in a viewbag, or a viewdata to be able to access it inside the view .

```
ViewBag.WeatherInfo = weatherInfo;
```

Then inside your view you can do :

```
var weatherInfo = ViewBag.WeatherInfo as WeatherInfo
```

This way you have access to your object inside the view

As requested here is how it can be used in your situation

```
@{
var weatherInfo = ViewBag.WeatherInfo as WeatherInfo 
}

<table id="tblWeather" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display:none">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">
        Weather Information
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3">
        <img id="imgWeatherIcon" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span id="citycountry">@weatherInfo.name , @weatherInfo.sys.country</span>
        <img id="imageurl" src="your image link" />
        <span id="des">@weatherInfo.weather.First().description</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: adam yes I have used model class to capture api responses.And plz do write some more code so i can understand easily.how can i use in view

Comment: could you tell me how to use var weatherInfo = ViewBag.WeatherInfo as WeatherInfo in view??

Comment: unfortunately the "as weatherinfo " show error in view I have to make some changes in controller but I am not able to do it.

Comment: @AdilYar ViewBag is dynamic , which means you can do WeatherInfo weatherInfo = viewbag.WeatherInfo; 
What type of error are you getting . 
Also don't foget to fully qualify the WeatherInfo namespace when declaring it inside the view